# Почему, когда перезагружаешь страницу, карусель из картинок не показывается

Tags: javascript

Почему, когда перезагружаешь страницу, карусель из картинок при открытии модального окна не показывается, а видно пустоту, но если нажать на любую другую кнопку все, становится нормальным и видимым. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать красивый вид сразу же после перезагрузки, а не после нажатия на кнопки?

```js
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick-1.6.0/slick/slick.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick-1.6.0/slick/slick-theme.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="slick-1.6.0/slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".thumbs").slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        centerMode: false,
  draggable: true, 
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 5
      });
 $(".thumbs a").click(function(){
  var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
  $("#largeImg").attr({ src: largePath });; return false;
 }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Сымитируем "нажатие на любую другую кнопку" во время загрузки:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".thumbs").slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    centerMode: false,
    draggable: true, 
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 5
  });
  $(".thumbs a").click(function(){
    var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#largeImg").attr({ src: largePath });
    return false;
  });

  $(".thumbs a").eq(0).click(); // !!!
});
```

Comment: Идея не плохая.. Но все равно не работает... Когда страница перезагружается в каруселе содержимое блока не видно, хотя сам блок пустой просматривается, и кнопки же появляются только тогда, когда картинок становится больше определенного числа, а значит если меньше то не сможет показать вообще, так как не будет кнопок и куда нажать. А примерно почему так происходит? и это именно в модальном окне, потому что когда делаю отдельно страницу все сразу появляется, даже после перезагрузке, а как только запихиваю в модалку. так происходит..Но мне надо что бы так работало именно в модальном окне

Comment: @alan Спасибо за то, что Вы так в меня верите. Могу погадать на кофейной гуще. Например, Вы подгружаете часть страницы динамически, и ее в этот момент просто еще нет.

Comment: а как можно это исправить?

Comment: @alan Что исправить? Я угадал что ли? Надeюсь, Вы понимаете, что способа показать что-то, чего еще нет в браузере, пока не изобрели. Вызывайте `$(".thumbs a").eq(0).click();`, когда контент придет в браузер.